# How to get all of the pages and files with status of a website using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I used this [one](https://github.com/alecxe/broken-links-checker) as base of my script to get all of the pages with their status. But how to check if the files(images, downloadables[pdf,doc], CSS, etc.) referenced on those pages do exists? I'm completely new with Python and this is my current code:

```
class BrokenItem(Item):
url = Field()
referer = Field()
status = Field()
type = Field()

class BrokenLinksSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = config.name
allowed_domains = config.allowed_domains
start_urls = config.start_urls
handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

def parse_item(self, response):
        item = BrokenItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['referer'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer')
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['type'] = 'page'

        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `HEAD` request. These requests do not download the content only headers which explain what the content is.

For example you can check:

```
if response.headers['Content-Length'] > 0:  
    #check whether the body is not empty
if 'image' in response.headers['Content-Type']:
    # check whether the content is an image
```

to make a HEAD request in scrapy use `method='HEAD'` keyword argument when creating `Request`, i.e. `Request('http://scrapy.org',method='HEAD')`

Now you need to figure out how to check all of your fields you want to, there are a lot of ways to do it depending on desired speed and complexity. Easiest way would probably be either chain requests in the spider itself or check every field in scrapy's [item pipelines.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will try those. Though, I'm still totally new with Python.